# Reactions involving photovoltaic cell

Tags: thermodynamics

I am trying to find a reaction that governs the mechanism of photovoltaic cell, that is, the chemical reaction. I already google it but couldn't find any font. I would appreciate if you share your knowledge about the reaction.

Comment: PV cells are not based on a chemical reaction, so it's unclear what you are asking.  Could you please elaborate?

Comment: The process can be viewed as a chemical reaction, but this is pretty much unusual.

Comment: @fraxinus - well, the detailed balance of electrons and holes is pretty important.

Comment: It can be done in organic solar cells, where it is easy to identify a molecular entity (or a couple of two different ones) undergoing what can be classifies as solid state photo-redox, or in classic PV effect (at the end discovered by plunging two electrodes in a solution). This reaction leads to long living radical cations and anions, then transported to the electrodes by hopping. Hopping in this case is basically a redox too, tough in a classical reaction nothing would really change. Driving force is the diffusion of the charged species, but just the charges move. At the end this leads...

Comment: ... to solid state physics treatment being (forcedly, in my opinion) used. But this kind of still academical solar cells is molecular in nature. It is somehow the mirror situation to which fraxinus refers to, as you push chemical concepts where they aren't really facts. This said, as black boxes, all solar cells are expected the same function.

Answer (score 1):

In the knowledge field of semiconductors, the boundary between the Chemistry and Physics is blurred and in fact not that much important.

In chemistry terms, in a silicon-based photovoltaic cell, you may think about a covalent bond between two Si atoms being photochemically broken into a free(-ish) electron and a delocalized positive charge. What happens next can be called chemistry only by forcing the definition of chemistry.

I think that for understanding the photovoltaic cell (as well as other varieties of the semiconductor diode) some chemical literacy is required, but the whole thing cannot be pushed into the chemistry frame.

Comment: I up vote and point to my comments under the OP question.